# error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver. con respectivas libreria

Tags: java, mysql, ant

buenas tardes estoy aprendiendo java y siguiendo un tutorial, la funcion del codigo es mostrar una ventana con un boton que dice conectar, al presionar se tendria que conectar a mi base de datos pero me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la ventana que me ayuda a conectarme con mi base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el codigo del tutorial que estoy siguiendo en el vídeo si se conecta sin ningun problema.

```
    package app;

import com.mysql.cj.protocol.Resultset;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class conexion extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/universidad_uaem";
    public static final String USERNAME = "root";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "luis1@java";

    public conexion() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btnConectar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnConectar.setText("conectar");
        btnConectar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnConectarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(146, 146, 146)
                .addComponent(btnConectar)
                .addContainerGap(179, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(147, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnConectar)
                .addGap(130, 130, 130))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnConectarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        try {
            Connection con = null;
            con = getConection();

            PreparedStatement ps;
            ResultSet res;

            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM persona");
            res = ps.executeQuery();

            if (res.next()) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, res.getString("nombre") + " " + res.getString("domicilio"));
            } else {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existen datos");
            }

            con.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }                                           

    public static Connection getConection() {
        Connection con = null;

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion exitosa");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return con;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new conexion().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnConectar;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

he intentado todas las soluciones que me he encontrado como poner la libreria, insertar el archivo.jar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aun así me sigue saliendo el mismo problema.

por cirto estoy utilizando netbeans para este proyecto

agradecere cualquier ayuda, gracias

Comment: La `D` de `driver` debe estar en mayúscula: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`, de todos modos, desde JDBC 4 no necesitas usar `Class.forName`, puedes conectar directamente invocado a `DriverManager.getConnection`, revisa el ejemplo en el apartado [Example 7.1 Connector/J: Obtaining a connection from the DriverManager](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) (segundo bloque de código).

Comment: muchas gracias.